# Html Agility Pack - Remove Tags by ID Or Class

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Here is my simplified HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="mainDiv">
       <div id="divToRemove"></div>
       <div id="divToKeep"></div>
       <div class="divToRemove"></div>
       <div class="divToRemove"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to remove the divs with ID or class named "divToRemove"
and  then I want to select only the div called "mainDiv" (in a HtmlNode).

The results should be:

```
   <div id="mainDiv">
       <div id="divToKeep"></div>
   </div>
```

How can i do that using Html Agility Pack?

Thanks!

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code is a adapted from [this Html Agility Pack forum page](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/248692) to fit your needs.  Essentially, we will grab all divs and then loop through them and check their class or their id for a match.  If it's there remove it.

```
var divs = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div");
if (divs != null)
{
    foreach (var tag in divs)
    {
        if (tag.Attributes["class"] != null && string.Compare(tag.Attributes["class"].Value, "divToRemove", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            tag.Remove();
        } else if(tag.Attributes["id"] != null && string.Compare(tag.Attributes["id"].Value, "divToRemove", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0) {
            tag.Remove();
        }
    }
}
```

You can also combine these if statements into one large if statement, but I thought this read better for the answer.

Finally, select the node you were looking for...

```
var mainDiv = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='mainDiv']");
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer to use the Linq methods of HtmlAgilityPack. The select will be long, but relatively straightforward—just select the nodes with the right id and/or class and then call the `Remove()` method on it.

```
foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
    .Where(n => n.Id.Equals("divToRemove", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) 
        || n.GetAttributeValue("class", string.Empty).Equals("divToRemove", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
    node.Remove();
HtmlNode mainNode = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(n => n.Id.Equals("mainDiv", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).First();
```

Comment: Does this work for you? This gives me an `Object Reference Not Set` error because not all divs have `class` attribute defined.

Comment: The second parameter of GetAttributeValue is what to return if there's no "class" attribute. Which is why I set it to string.Empty. That way there's no object reference issue on that method. You may want to verify that's where your bad reference is, though...