# How to substring html string based on div id

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, string, html-agility-pack

If I have a string in html format like this:

```html
<p style="text-align:center">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align:center">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align:center"><strong>To The &lrm;<span>Embassy of The United Kingdom</span>&rlm;</strong></p>
<p>The ORG- certifies that &lrm;<strong><span>Mrs.</span></strong>&rlm;&lrm;<strong>&nbsp;</strong>&rlm;&lrm;<strong><span>Matilda Johan</span></strong>&rlm;,</p>
<p>has been&lrm;&rlm;&lrm;&rlm; working since&nbsp;<strong><span>01/10/2003</span></strong>&rlm; until present.</p>
<p>&lrm;<span>Presently, she is working as</span>&rlm;&lrm;&rlm;&lrm;&nbsp; a / an &lrm;<strong><span>JOB TITLE NOT DEFINED</span></strong>&rlm; at&nbsp;<strong><span>Dean of the Faculty of Engineering and Technology Office - College of Engineering and Technology - S</span></strong>&rlm;-&lrm;​​​​​​​&rlm;&lrm;​​​&lrm;<strong><span>College of Engineering and Technology </span></strong>&rlm;.</p>
<p><strong>This certificate was issued upon&nbsp;</strong>&lrm;<strong><span>her request</span></strong>&rlm;​​​​​​​&nbsp;<strong>and without any commitment on behalf of the ORG.</strong></p>
<div>
  <div id="dv_sign_en" style="float:left;clear:both;font-style: italic;">...</div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

How to get the string only before the parent div for the div with id start with `dv_sign_` so the result will be:

```
<p style="text-align:center">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align:center">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align:center"><strong>To The &lrm;<span>Embassy of The United Kingdom</span>&rlm;</strong></p>
<p>The ORG- certifies that &lrm;<strong><span>Mrs.</span></strong>&rlm;&lrm;<strong>&nbsp;</strong>&rlm;&lrm;<strong><span>Matilda Johan</span></strong>&rlm;,</p>
<p>has been&lrm;&rlm;&lrm;&rlm; working since&nbsp;<strong><span>01/10/2003</span></strong>&rlm; until present.</p>
<p>&lrm;<span>Presently, she is working as</span>&rlm;&lrm;&rlm;&lrm;&nbsp; a / an &lrm;<strong><span>JOB TITLE NOT DEFINED</span></strong>&rlm; at&nbsp;<strong><span>Dean of the Faculty of Engineering and Technology Office - College of Engineering and Technology - S</span></strong>&rlm;-&lrm;​​​​​​​&rlm;&lrm;​​​&lrm;<strong><span>College of Engineering and Technology </span></strong>&rlm;.</p>
<p><strong>This certificate was issued upon&nbsp;</strong>&lrm;<strong><span>her request</span></strong>&rlm;​​​​​​​&nbsp;<strong>and without any commitment on behalf of the ORG.</strong></p>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0

Comment: This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371821/html-agility-pack-remove-tags-by-id-or-class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Html Agility Pack - Remove Tags by ID Or Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371821/html-agility-pack-remove-tags-by-id-or-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```csh
    String html;

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader($@"D:\OneDrive\Dokumentumok\Projects\html.txt")) {
        html = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    Int32 index = html.IndexOf("<div id=\"dv_sign_");
    html = html.Substring(0, index);

    index = html.LastIndexOf("<div>");
    html = html.Substring(0, index);
```

Comment: How can I specify the language identifier to be C#? `csh` doesn't work.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting